# DataBind User Control and return HTML String

Tags: c#, data-binding, webforms

I am currently trying to get a little functionality from Web Forms User Controls.  The idea is to use it in a manner similar to MVC's PartialView.  What I want to do is create the control from code, have data binding occur with the `ASP Repeater` server control then return the rendered HTML from the method.

Currently, I am using the following code to define the user control:

```
<table id="comments">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>By</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater ID="commentsRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="user-comment">
                    <td><%#Eval("ReviewedOn")%></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Reviewer")%></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Comment")%></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I put the databinding code in the Load event, nothing occurs.  If I put it into a method and call it I receive the following exception:
`Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in controls contained in a page.`

So how can I use a User control to get the results I want?

**UPDATE:**

This is how I currently attempt databinding (This way doesn't bind anything but does return the surrounding html string)

```
public partial class UserComments : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public List<CallReview> Comments;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        commentsRepeater.DataSource = Comments;
        commentsRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Adding code on how I am attempting to load the control to get the HTML representation.

```
//Will be used to load the control
var loader = new UserControl();
var ctl = (UserComments)loader.LoadControl("~/Controls/UserComments.ascx");

//Set the comments property of the control
ctl.Comments = _callAdapter.GetCallComments(callId);

//Create streams the control will be rendered to
TextWriter txtWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(txtWriter);

//Render the control and write it to the stream
ctl.RenderControl(writer);

//Return the HTML
return txtWriter.ToString();
```

Comment: How are you binding it?  If in the `Page_Load` for the user control you set the `.DataSource` of the `Repeater` to your collection, this should work.

Comment: @David Added code showing how the databinding occurs

Comment: And this doesn't bind the data?  Is `Page_Load` being invoked?  Maybe the problem is in how you're using the user control?  Show that as well.

Comment: @David Updated code to show

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured out a work around.  Instead of using the `UserControl` object, I use the `Page` object to render the control as it will render the server controls properly.  After this, I had to wrap my html code in a `form` object with `runat="server"`.  Now I have no issues getting it.

Downside is that I still have to make a call do databind the repeater as the `Load` event is never raised.

**Control:**

```
<form runat="server">
<table id="user-comments">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Created On</th>
            <th>By</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater ID="commentsRepeater" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class="user-comment">
                    <td><%#Eval("ReviewedOn")%></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Reviewer")%></td>
                    <td><%#Eval("Comment")%></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

**Code-behind**:

```
    public partial class UserComments : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public List<CallReview> Comments;

        public void BindComments()
        {
            commentsRepeater.DataSource = Comments;
            commentsRepeater.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

**Code to render the control and get the raw HTML:**

```
//Will be used to load the control
var loader = new Page();
var ctl = (UserComments)loader.LoadControl("~/Controls/UserComments.ascx");

//Set the comments property of the control
ctl.Comments = _callAdapter.GetCallComments(callId);
ctl.BindComments();

//Create streams the control will be rendered to
TextWriter txtWriter = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(txtWriter);

//Render the control and write it to the stream
ctl.RenderControl(writer);

//Return the HTML
return txtWriter.ToString();
```